# How to configure web server rewrites

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite, server-setup

I tried to 'Use Web Server Rewrites', but it does not work.

Can you help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Apache, make sure the `.htaccess` file exists. If not, copy it from `.htaccess.sample`

If you are using nginx, refer to this wiki: https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Configuring+nginx+for+Magento+1.x

Comment: that page was not updated, config is broken...

Comment: thanks for the reply;  .htaccess What should be the content?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure [Apache mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is enabled. Also it is not recommended to use `localhost`, configure [Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) instead.

Comment: What about using virtual host?